# is there a way to find the common topological sort between two graphs

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

If I have two graphs, A and B that have the same set of vertices (1,2,3,4....n) I need a way to find at least one topological sort with all the elements (1,2,3,4....n) that both graphs have in common. Is there a way to do this?

I thought of finding  all the topological sorts in graphs A and B using Kahn's method, storing them in a 2d array each and comparing them to find the common one, but this gives me a time complexity slower than O(N^2) with N being the number of vertices in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a new graph C combining A and B by putting an edge (u,v) if it is in either A or B. If it admits a topological sort, it will be a common topological sort, otherwise there will be a cycle from which you can deduce such a topological graph doesn't exist. This solution has complexity O(m) where m is the total number of edges in both graphs.